# Bootstrap collapse only showing class .collapsed after first click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I’m not sure if I’m setting this up wrong but the default Bootstap collapse/accordion is only adding.

```
  <a class="collapsed"> </a>
```

After you’ve clicked either button the first time it shows and doesn’t show as it should.

I need the page to load with the class collapsed already there, then function on and off as it does after you’ve clicked.

Set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exebz2uz/13/) basically the two links should be red straight away, but they only turn red after you’ve click either button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely odd that it does not put the collapsed class on there to begin with. You can work around it pretty easily with JavaScript though.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').addClass("collapsed");
```

That will just straight up add the class to the elements and allow your CSS style to properly apply.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a leftover class="panel-body" in the panel body declaration that made the problem.

`<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" align="left"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" align="center">3-PHASE CURRENT</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" align="right"><a href="#I-EFF-content" 
                data-toggle="collapse">Show/Hide</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div **class="panel-body"** id="I-EFF-content" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    </div>
</div>`

Taking away this part it started working as it should.